# Asus laptop powers on but has blackscreen with not even Asus logo popping up

Tags: laptop, windows-update, asus-laptop, black-screen-of-death, asus

My laptop is an ASUS Rog Strix.

So yesterday I turned on my laptop, and the Asus logo popped on with its sound, but then it turned itself off. I turned it on again because I was sure that I had charged it.

With the 2nd or 3rd turning on, the Windows update popped on the screen. It was like 15 or 20% done, I didn't watch it so I can't tell when exactly it happened, but the laptop turned itself off again during the update. Then I went home, charged it and since then when I try to turn it on, the keyboard lights on and fans start, but there is no longer the ASUS logo.

I called support and they asked me to press the power button for 60 seconds, then plug in the charger and try turning it on. They indicated that if that doesn't work, then I should try plugging it into the TV.

I did both, and it didn't work. I called my brother, and he told me to install linux ubuntu on pendrive but even the ASUS logo doesn't pop up anymore.

I also tried holding F2 and then turning the laptop on, but nothing happened.

So my questions are:

1. Can I do anything on my own to repair my laptop?
2. If not, can I do anything to get the data? I'd prefer not to send my laptop with data to the computer service, but if I can't do anything here, it's not that big of a deal for me.

Comment: Get the ASUS Hardware Diagnostics on bootable USB key (from ASUS) and check the main drive for errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My specific problem is that when I click power button, keyboard lights up, but there is nothing on screen, not even asus logo that used to pop before windows was starting.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any solution that I can try for my laptop to just run normaly. I hope that clarifies what problem I currently have eith my laptop and what I need.

Comment: Make sure the laptop is OFF.  Then attach the AC Adapter and let charge overnight. Does it start the next day?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems the battery was low, and during the update the power ran out completely. While that can cause serious issues with booting into Windows, the most likely reason for a completely dead PC is that the battery will not take a charge at all, now. New batteries such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GKK1LDN) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KG65D9S) can be found for ~$US50, but require [opening the case](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHzRq6FpyEc) to install. Other than taking the laptop in for professional repairs, the first thing to test would be the battery. **If you decide to replace the battery, be sure to get one designed for your particular model.**

As a test, you *might* try *removing* the battery completely to see if it will try to run from the AC adapter alone. If it does work, then get a replacement battery, **but do not use the laptop for more than a minute or two without a battery.** However, some laptops, particularly gaming machines such as the ASUS ROG Strix, require *so much* power that the AC supply alone is insufficient to boot the PC. If you have a friend with an **identical** PC, you might ask to borrow that battery for a test.

Note that an interrupted update can cause serious problems with the operating system that will need to be fixed after you get the machine to run at all. At that point, you might consider creating a [Windows installation USB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and reinstall Windows, keeping your files.

In the future, take care to maximize the service lifetime of the battery. Repeated cycling from fully charged to very low will kill the battery in a short time. Try to keep it between 80% and 30%. While that only allows the laptop to run half as long as cycling from 100% to 0%, it will *greatly* increase the battery service life, from months to years.

Comment: Most laptop batteries are pretty particular.  It's not often not even enough to have the same model from a different year, as the form factor changes or even the size of the battery might change.  I would not recommend trying to plug a battery from another laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound, point taken. "Similar" -> "identical" PC.